# MPAndroidChart How to add history Entries

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I created a LineChart in MPAndroidChart with a number of entries and I need to dynamically add entries at the start of the chart (like historical data)
Is it possible ? Or do I have to recreate whole dataset with new entries at the beginning, and set the data to chart ?

Comment: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Dynamic-&-Realtime-Data

Comment: I checked the wiki of course, but if I already have Entries with index 0 - 100, If I add use AddEntry((new Entry( float, index =0); but that just makes 2 entries on index 0. Or I can start to put Entries with index 1000 and later add Entries with indexes 999, 998 but that also do not works correctly.

Comment: Oh now I see what you want. I don't really see a way around creating a new LineDataSet right now. Have you tried addEntryOrdered?

Comment: When I see the code for addEntryOrdered, it should be possible to create new method addEntryAtStart()  where will be at the end just          mYVals.add(0, (T) e ); instead of         mYVals.add( (T) e ); as in addEntry();

Comment: I'm thinking about adding methods like `addStart(...)` that will allow what you are currently trying to achieve. For now the best solution is to increment all x-indices of the dataset and then add an entry to the beginning of the list.